# How to order a map with pig latin

Tags: dictionary, apache-pig

I was wondering how could I order a map by using pig latin, has anyone ever done this before, any help will be appreciated.

For example, my map:   {userid:001, segment:type1, userlanguage:US, timestamp:1111111111111, }

I want to have a map like this: {timestamp:1111111111, userid:001, userlanguage:US, segment:type1}

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

I think like this you can manage column order

```
A= LOAD 'path' using PigStorage(',') as (a int, b int, c int);
B= Foreach A generate $3 as c,$2 as b,$1 as a;
Describe B;
```

Comment: His asking to sort a map, not to rearrange some columns in a relation. You are rearranging `int`s in a manual way. OP asks for a way to automatically sort data *inside* a `map`.